# I can´t use getResource().getString in Android

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am overriding a method that returns a CharSequence and it returns charSequecence.
I have also tried returning a String. Here is the code

```
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return  getResource().getString(R.string.tabla_del) + ": " + (position + 1);
}
```

Comment: A `String` **IS** a `CharSequence`.

Comment: Please paste your stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, generally, three reasons to fail this:

**The first one,** no exists a Context. Solving this, you need to pass a context object to method that use it:

```
public String getPageTitle(Context context, int position) {
    return  context.getResource().getString(R.string.tabla_del) + ": " + (position + 1);
}
```

Context variable is passed from Activity/Fragment but it can be avoid if method exists inside a Activity/Fragment; there only need `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` method depends on if it's Activity or Fragment.

```
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return  getContext().getResource().getString(R.string.tabla_del) + ": " + (position + 1);
}
```

**The second one,** no exists `R` class imported. You should check if your class exists inside subpackages, for instance:
Your main package is `com.example.androidapp` it is described on AndroidManifest and gradle files. So, if your class exists on `com.example.androidapp.configuration` you need import `R` class from main package:

```
package com.example.androidapp.configuration
...
import com.example.androidapp.R;
...
public class Configuration {
    ...
}
```

**The third one,** no exists strings you need on **strings file**. Here you should create a strings files and add strings you need.

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.getResources().getString(R.string.tabla_del)+ ": " + (position + 1);
}
```

or

```
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return context.getResources().getString(R.string.tabla_del)+ ": " + (position + 1);
}
```